# resultset filtering in asp.net mvc 3 linq

Tags: c#, linq

Say i've a action of a controller like

```
   IList <post> p =db.posts.Include("user").ToList();


        if (Request.Form["searchString"] != null)          
        {
            if ((p!=null) && (p.Any()))

            {
                p =(p.Where(a=>a.area==Request 
                .Form["searchString"]).Tolist();                                
            }
       }           
        if (Request.Form["searchString2"] != null)          
        {              
            if ((p!=null) && (p.Any()))

            {


            p=(p.Where(a=>a.city==Request 
          .Form["searchString2"]).Tolist();                                            
            }
        }  
      return View(p);
```

here first i've get a resultset(p). then i want to filter p by some criterias.it gives error for the ToList() inside the condition block. error: **there is no definition for tolist() in the post**

Comment: Ideas about what? What is your request? Have you tried the code you wrote? What's the problem with it?

Comment: as far I can see you do not need List. IEnumerable of students will be just fine.

Comment: please now check out my question again ...

Answer (score 0):

it would be:

```
 if ((rs!=null) && (rs.Any()))
     {
     rs = (from posts1 in rs where                   
     posts1.area="Dhaka").ToList() ;                             
     }
```

just consider that if you call .`ToList()` or `Any` it will go to DB (in case you are using a ORM)

Comment: it gives error for the ToList() inside the condition block. error: there is no definition for tolist() in the post

Comment: weird.. according to your code it says "Tolist()", maybe it is just a typo, the correct syntax is "ToList()"

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredRS=rs.Where(s=>s.area=="Dhaka").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter directly:

```
List <student> rs = db.students.Where(student => student.area == "Dhaka").ToList();
```

or:

```
List <student> filtered = rs.Where(student => student.area == "Dhaka").ToList();
```

Comment: Well, you need to first declare `rs` before using it: `List<student> rs = db.students.ToList();`.

Comment: What condition block? Look at my example. There are no condition blocks anywhere.